# How to attach a file (file upload)in RestClient 2.0.3 plugin

Tags: java, rest, rest-client

I am trying to upload a file using restclient 2.0.3 plugin,

I tried using content-disposition ,but here i have to paste the file content , My requirement is if i specify the path , it should take the content . Do any one know , how to upload the File in restclient.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Use Postman Rest client. 
Make sure you set the method to Post.

This extension will meet your requirements.

Comment: @user3545493- my requirement was to use only restclient debugger 2.0.3 and i should only use firefox browser.

Comment: The feature you are requesting is not supported.Please see this link: https://github.com/chao/RESTClient/issues/114